# useEffect Hook dependencies and useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my app I have a state property that would only change once at login and that is it.
I want to know if it is bad coding or bad practice to have the useEffect state dependency that is updated inside the same useEffect

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

useEffect(() => {
    const newState = updateState();
    setState(newState);
    // do something with updated state property
}, [state]);
```

Or is it preferable to have two distinct useEffect one that is called each time on component loading/updating (even if the value of the state property won't change) and the other that is reacting on the change (but called only once because the value of the state property won't change).

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("called each time the component is updated");
    const newState = updateState();
    setState(newState); // state value change only once
});

useEffect(() => { // called only once as state property value won't change once computed
    // do something with newState property
    // but does not update the state => no call to setState
}, [state]);
```

Comment: Both of these idea are infinite loops. If an effect runs every time `state` is updated AND it updates state, it will render the component forever.

Comment: if you share the code that led to this conundrum I can show what the effects should be, and why.

Comment: In the second code snippet, the second useEffect hook does not update the state, setState is never called in this hook. But I guess I have my answer, the first code snippet is bad. I think the second is fine but I there will be a call to updateState everytime the component is rerendered which is useless.

Comment: I have just seen that I can use the second parameter of the useEffect hook as an empty list of dependencies so that is runs only once.  I think it should be fine now, thank you.